# What is the nature of Finn's injury?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In previous *Star Wars* films lightsaber duels with a clear winner ended in one of two ways, death or dismemberment for the loser.  In *The Force Awakens* Finn was slashed by Ren, falls unconscious and remains so for the rest of the film.  **What exactly happened to Finn?**

Comment: He got lightsabered hard.

Comment: His character got [semi-killed](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81fwac5lCML._SL1500_.jpg) in case he wouldn't sign on for the sequel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finn suffered a substantial cut to the shoulder and a slashing wound to the back (his chest in the novel) as well as multiple soft-tissue injuries and a punch to the face. Although the major wounds were evidently cauterised by the lightsaber, he would still have likely gone into [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_(circulatory)) from the extent of the trauma

> Advancing relentlessly, he was driven by something that Finn could not
> even sense, far less counter. Still the ex-trooper fought back, until
> Ren landed a blow that cut across Finn’s chest and sent the lightsaber
> flying from his hand.

...

> Below them, Rey huddled beside the unconscious Finn. Turning him over,
> she recoiled from the wound Ren had inflicted with his lightsaber. The
> blow had cauterized instantly. In the dim light she couldn’t estimate
> its depth, nor if it had passed through any vital organs. Holding the
> unresponsive body in her arms, she started to cry. There were worse
> ways to die, she told herself as the ground continued to shake and
> trees began to topple around her.

After his rescue, he was placed into a medically induced coma to allow him to recover more fully.

> Within the intensive care pod in the medical center, Finn lay in a
> medically induced coma, his health and life still very much in the
> balance. Dr. Kalonia’s prognosis had been favorable, even positive,
> but nothing certain could be said until Finn had fully recovered. When
> wholly parsed, the phrase “be all right” could mean one thing to a
> physician and something else entirely to the patient.

<sub><sup>All quotes from [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

There has now been positive confirmation that Finn's injuries were not life-threatening and that with a bacta dip, he'll be as right as rain, just in time to star in the sequel.

> Finn had a nasty encounter with a lightsaber during his duel with Kylo
> Ren. Luckily, it seems Kylo didn’t hit anything vital, and with the
> help of a suit full of healing bacta, Finn should be up and about in
> no time. He’s going to wonder what has happened to Rey in his absence
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Made Easy: A Beginner's Guide to a Galaxy Far, Far Away](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Made_Easy:_A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_a_Galaxy_Far,_Far_Away)</sup></sub>

Comment: hmmm interesting if I remember the film right......there it was the back that was hit not the chest.

Comment: @Thomas - You are indeed correct. In the film, Ren sucker-punches Finn. He spins around and Ren makes a slashing cut up his back.